# Display results from DB using Bootstrap

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to retrieve my results from my DB in this format using Bootstrap.
Below is my PHP code that I'm currently using, the first entry I want the image to be bigger then the rest.

[image]

```
<?php
$article = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "blog");
 
// Check connection
if($article === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
 

 
// Attempt select query execution
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news";
if($result = mysqli_query($article, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo "<container>";
            echo "<row>";
                echo "<th>id</th>";
                echo "<th>title</th>";
                echo "<th>body</th>";
                echo "<th>image</th>";
            echo "</div>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<row>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['body'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['image'] . "</td>";
            echo "</row>";
        }
        echo "</div>";
        // Free result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($article);
}
 
// Close connection
mysqli_close($article);
?>
```

Comment: you need to do a little more research on bootstrap, create the expected output without php then implement the php part, as-is there is nothing about your current code which would produce anything close to the image and to answer would require a rewrite of your current code

Comment: example: https://playcode.io/800989/

Comment: That's pretty close to what I'm looking for.

Comment: @CPuser, this is the fastest way to get the result you need: (1) look for a website similar to the design you desire; (2) check if it is a bootstrap website, and (3) take the part of the code you need to place in yours. You should take into account the bootstrap version, as you should refer the same bootstrap `.js` and `.css` to get the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have the condition to check for the first data in your loop to apply a bigger image size.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add condition:

```
$resultNum = 1;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    
    if($resultNum == 1) {
        // TODO: show bigger image
    } else {
        // usual image
        echo "<row>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['body'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['image'] . "</td>";
        echo "</row>";
    }
    
    $resultNum++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a counter and then do a condition using the first number of the counter

Your code simplyfied:

```
$query = mysqli_query($article, "SELECT * FROM news");

$n = 1; //start the counter

if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){ //detect if have rows

    foreach ($query as $key => $value) {

        if($n == 1){
            //print the big image
            echo $value["id"];
        }else{
            //print the little image
            echo $value["id"];
        }
        
        $n++;
    }

}else{
    echo "No data founded";
}
```

Comment: This is very close to what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: @CPuser tell me what more do you need, so i can try to improve!